# Bash - for looping a curl gives no output

Tags: for-loop, curl

so, I am currently trying to connect Data from a Consul Cluster with those from FNT. I get the Data I need by curling for it in the Consul API and the returning Server names shall be checked against FNT to get the Server owner.

Following is the Consul curl:

`gethosts=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" <CONSUL URL> | jq -cr '.[] | select(.NodeMeta.type == "physical") | .ServiceAddress')`

Following is the FNT curl:

`curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k -X POST -d '{}' "<FNT URL>" | jq '.returnData[] | select(.cFqdn == "<FQDN>") | .cResponsible + "/" + .cFqdn'`

Both work perfectly fine on their own. The Consul Curl gets me every FQDN from every physical (hardware) hosts and if i paste one of those FQDNs into the FNT curl it gets me the FQDN again + the responsible Owner for that server.

Now i wanted to combine those in a loop to get every single FQDN from Consul checked against FNT with the following:

`for i in $gethosts; do curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k -X POST -d '{}' "<FNT URL>" | jq '.returnData[] | select(.cFqdn == $i) | .cResponsible + " " + .cFqdn'; done`

But it simply doesnt work. There is no error or anything i can work with. Just no output at all.

Does anyone of you see the mistake in my for loop? cause I definitely can't, probably already code blind after all those hours of troubleshooting :D

Thanks in advance!

P.S.:
I also tried

`for i in $gethosts; do $(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k -X POST -d '{}' "<FNT URL>" | jq '.returnData[] | select(.cFqdn == $i) | .cResponsible + " " + .cFqdn'); done`

or

`for i in $gethosts; do curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k -X POST -d '{}' "<FNT URL>" | jq '.returnData[] | select(.cFqdn == <FQDN>) | .cResponsible + " " + .cFqdn'; done`

For my understanding, the last one should always have the Same outpout but as many times as hosts are in $gethosts. I did this to see if $i in .cFqdn is the problem, but it seems like it isnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.

`for a in $gethosts; do curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k -X POST -d '{}' "<FNTURL>" | jq "[.returnData[] | select(.cFqdn == \"$a\") | .cResponsible + \";\" + .cFqdn] | .[]"; done`

Guess I had some quoting issues.